# I cannot run Windows without connecting the flash drive in which linux was installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, flash

I've installed Linux into my flashdrive from another flash drive while windows 7 is running. When I start up my computer with the flash drive in which linux installed , it appears 4 options ( Linux, Linux recovery, window , windows recovery ).Linux used to work smoothly but something happened and I could not open linux again. Terminal screen appears but it says there is a problem with system file . But I still get 4 options in start-up and I can open windows 7 if I connect the flash drive.

But the problem is I cannot run Windows  without connecting the flash drive in which linux was installed.When I disconnect the flash drive and start up the computer in a usual way, windows logo never appears and black screen appears and it says like " welcome to grub..there is no such a device..recovery mode.."

So how can I run windows directly like in the past? I worry if I lose the flash drive I will not able to run windows either.

Comment: GRUB is set as your primary boot manager, and it's relying on files stored on your USB flash drive. How to fix this depends on details you haven't provided. To provide them, run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (part of the `boot-info-script` package in Ubuntu), which will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to a [pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here.

Comment: @RodSmith Thanks for your help. I decide to choose Windows 7 recovery on start-up screen and I write  BootRec.exe /fixmbr on DOS.That's it.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run Windows again, either grab your Windows Installation Disk, or make a Windows Recovery Disk. There are many tutorials on the subject, so I don't need to explain to you how. After you make your disk or find it, put it in your computer and access the BIOS by pressing a key during the boot-up process (usually F2, F10) and boot from your CD/USB. Once the installation menu or recovery menu pops up, open the command prompt and type this: **BootRec.exe /fixmbr**. This will allow you to boot back into Windows and make it the default loader when switching between operating systems. You'll be good to go.